# ubuntu-keyring cannot be updated

Tags: apt, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot update the `ubuntu-keyring` package on my Ubuntu WSL.

I tried to run `sudo apt update ubuntu-keyring` and this is the command output:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ubuntu-keyring
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 91158 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-keyring_2018.09.18.1-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-keyring (2018.09.18.1-4) over (2012.05.19) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-keyring_2018.09.18.1-4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg', which is also in package ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring 2013.11.11
Warning: The postinst maintainerscript of the package ubuntu-keyring
Warning: seems to use apt-key (provided by apt) without depending on gnupg or gnupg2.
Warning: This will BREAK in the future and should be fixed by the package maintainer(s).
Note: Check first if apt-key functionality is needed at all - it probably isn't!
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package ubuntu-keyring)
Warning: 'apt-key update' is deprecated and should not be used anymore!
Note: In your distribution this command is a no-op and can therefore be removed safely.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-keyring_2018.09.18.1-4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I also tried to download the `ubuntu-keyring_2018.09.18.1-4_all.deb` file and then install it using `sudo dpkg --install ubuntu-keyring_2018.09.18.1-4_all.deb`, but the same error shows up.